# addClass and class to be added is part name and part variable

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

Working with the YUI library and I have the following:

```
var levelnumber = 3;
```

I want to add a class to a div so that it says ".level3" , so the class to be added should be the word "level" plus the value of the variable.

Something like this but Im not sure on the syntax:

```
addClass("level"+[levelnumber]);
```

I have tried quite a few combinations of single and double quotation marks but cant get it to work.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Sorry fellas!

I asked the wrong question.

I have that part sorted actually, my problem is not with adding the class, it is with **selecting** a class!

I want to select **.group .level3**

```
var level = 3;
Y.all(".group" '.level'+[levelnumber])
```

That is what I have now but don't know where all the quoatation marks should go.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the square brackets. As long as one of the variables is a string, it will concatenate them together. **[Here's](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html)** a good article on strings in JavaScript.

```
addClass('level'+ levelnumber);
```

Comment: thanks, i asked the wrong question but this and your link was very helpful, too!

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
<div id="foo" class="bar">foo</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">   

 var addClass = function(level) { 
   YAHOO.util.Dom.addClass('foo',"level"+ level ); 
 };

 addClass(3); 
</script>
```